# Font selection on Android devices

Tags: bug

I'm not sure what other devices this affects, but certainly on stock Nexus 7s (both the first generation and the 2013 model) using Chrome, the font that gets selected for code blocks is not mono-spaced so my little ASCII entity diagrams (such as the one in [Many to many link tables with history?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/many-to-many-link-tables-with-history/51316#51316)), and peoples sample data tables, fall apart somewhat.

Is this something that can be addressed without breaking the layout for other user agents?

Comment: Can someone replicate? It's a no-repro on a S4 running 4.2.2 and [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/51347) answer

Comment: FYI: I'm seeing variable spaced fonts for everything on that page on the N7(2013) too. I don't have a G1 N7 handy to retest on there.